# C# String Array Returns Wrong Values

Tags: c#, arrays, string

When i run my program i get wrong values from string array and i have no idea why this is happening...

My code :

```
BackGroundWorker bgw = new BackGroundWorker();
Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bgw.DoWork += delegate {
        Open();
    }
    bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
private void Open()
{
    string line = "put --------------------,true,10,0";

    var lineContent = line.Split(' ');
    var syx = lineContent[0];
    var cont = lineContent[1];
    var contents = cont.Split(',');

    if (syx == "put")
    {
        if (contents.Length == 4) // In Debug This Is True
        {
            // Debugger : contents[0] = "-------------------"
            //                    [1] = "true"
            //                    [2] = "10"
            //                    [3] = "0"
            string m = contents[0]; // m = " "
            string r = contents[1]; // r = "true"
            string s = contents[2]; // s = "1"
            string rnd = contents[3]; // rnd = "0"
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see , my `contents` array have the correct values but when i try to get values form my array , it gives me wrong or incomplete values
[image: Debugger]
Is my code wrong ? or something else ?

Comment: Please read [ask]. _How_ do you try "to get them from it"? _What_ means wrong? What did you expect and _what do you get instead_?

Comment: Start by using meaningful variable names, then your problem becomes apparent.

Comment: sorry my english is no too good...

Comment: @CodeCaster Good now ?

Comment: @alix54 I've attempted to change the code to something that compiles without hopefully changing it beyond the question, which isn't very clear. What output do you expect?

Comment: @alix54  i think after the edit, the code is giving proper output as shown in debug output.  I think it is fixed.

Comment: the previous version did not even compile, it is unclear how the debugger observations could have been made

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth as you can see my variables isn't equal to my `contents` values , so i need the correct values

Comment: @alix54 Oh, so you expect an empty string for the first element and `1` and `0` for the final elements instead of `10` and `10`?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Yes, also my first string should be `------...`

Comment: How does that even compile?

Comment: @Lostblue This is not the full codes...

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of your Locals window at the end of the `if (contents.Length == 4)` block so we can see the values of `contents`, `m`, `r`, `s`, and `rnd` in the debugger?

Comment: Even without the full code...
`BackGroundWorker` do you mean `BackgroundWorker`?
`.Remove()` on a `string[]`?

Comment: @Abion47 I wrote the local values of debugger for you in my codes as comments

Comment: I see that you did, but your situation is not making sense with the information you have supplied. Showing a screenshot will give a better picture of what is actually going on than having it all transcribed. (I'm just trying to weed out human error here.)

Comment: Not to mention there are all the concerns regarding how your code wouldn't even compile in its current state from what you have given us. A screenshot of the debugger would also demonstrate that you can actually run it.

Comment: @Abion47 Picture Of Debugger Added.

Comment: Copying your current code within `Open` performs as expected. Try restarting your Visual Studio to see if your debugger is just bugging out.

Comment: @alix54 did you ignore build error warnings when you tried debugging? Given that your code wouldn't even compile, how could you run the debugger? Most likely, you were debugging the executable of some earlier attempt while reading the broken code

Answer (score -1):

Check this:

```
string[] lineContent = new string[] { };
string syx = "";
string cont = "";
string[] contents = new string[] { };
string er = "";

string line = "put --------------------,true,10,10";
lineContent = line.Split(' ');
syx = lineContent[0];
cont = lineContent[1];
contents = cont.Split(',');

if (syx == "put")
{
  if (contents.Length == 4) // In Debug This Is True
  {
    // Debugger : contents[0] = "-------------------"
    //                    [1] = "true"
    //                    [2] = "10"
    //                    [3] = "10"
    string m = contents[0]; // m = " "
    string r = contents[1]; // r = "true"
    string s = contents[2]; // s = "1"
    string rnd = contents[3]; // rnd = "0"
  }

}
```

Comment: What is the changes ?

Comment: First it will split by space, then rest of the string will split by comma and assign the values to variables m,r,s and rnd.

Comment: I posted the this answer before you edit your question

Comment: @imsome1 You shoudln't have posted the "correct answer" right away, now there is no problem and you will be criticized because of a stupid edit.
In the first place his code had syntax error not even worth calling it a question.

Comment: @Lostblue what should I do? any suggestions please

Comment: @Lostblue what if I delete my answer?

Comment: People, don't downvote this answer. The original question was full of syntax errors. This answer actually *fixed* the errors.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed by using different variable names ... don't know why , But this way my issue fixed.

Comment: In fact you didn't even tried in the first place? imsome1 answer was correct (please remove your edit)

Comment: Did you ignore build errors when you tried to debug the *original question's* code that didn't compile?

Comment: My Program Ran Correct and WITHOUT Errors , i dont know what cause this